# Help in finding $z$ coordinate of centroid by triple integration

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

We are given a cone  $z^2 = x^2 +y^2$ and between the spheres $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$

Also the mass density is equal to $z$ and we are asked z coordinate of centroid of volume inside the cone and above the xy plane.

Now for z coordinate of centroid $$I = \iiint \rho z\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ divided by mass $M$.

So now translating to spherical coordinates we get
 $$I=\iiint \rho  zr^2\sin\theta\, dr\, d\theta\, d\phi$$

As volume inside the cone is asked then z lies between $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and the plane $z = 2$.
Evaluating that after putting the value of x and y in spherical coordinate and $r$ between 2 and 1, $\rho$ = z I am getting the wrong answer. Have I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Where is the plane $z=2$ coming from ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust if we consider the sphere r = 2 then for $x^2 + y^2 = 4$  z =2. So the cone is capped by the plane z =2.

Comment: First, the intersection of the cone and the sphere is given by $x^2+y^2+z^2=z^2+z^2=4$ hence $z=\sqrt2$. Second, it is nowhere said that the cone has planar bases.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following image, projection on the $yz$ plane

[image]

[image]

we have
\begin{align}
&\int_1^2dr\int_0^{\pi/4}d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\,(r\cos\theta)r^2\sin\theta=\\
&2\pi\int_1^2dr\int_0^{\pi/4}d\theta\,r^3\sin\theta\cos\theta=\\
&2\pi\int_1^2dr\,r^3\left.\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\theta\right)\right|_0^{\pi/4}=\\
&\frac{\pi}{2}\int_1^2dr\,r^3=\\
&\frac{\pi}{2}\left.\left(\frac{1}{4}r^4\right)\right|_1^2=\frac{15}{8}\pi\\
\end{align}

Comment: Can you please explain why the limit is from 0 to $\pi / 4$ ? Also shouldn't it be $rcos \theta$ squared as $\rho = z$?

Comment: In [spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates) $z$ is exactly $r\cos\theta$, and the cone has its generating lines $\pi/4$ away from the vertical axis.

Comment: Okay I get it but why isn't there a $z^2$ ? The mass density is also z .

Comment: @user127: this is indeed the calculation for the mass, as you noticed, you need an extra $z$ for the $z$ coordinate of the centroid.